# Pyspark - convert a flat dataframe to struct type

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, struct, apache-spark-sql

I need to convert a flat dataframe to nested struct type in pyspark
Input looks like -

```
 root
 |-- id: struct (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- created_at: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

I need to dynamically(with 20+ columns in reality) convert into below structure and also change the datatypes -

```
root
 |-- payload: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- after: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- created_at: long (nullable = true)
```

please note - timestamp datatype need to convert to long.

How to do this in pyspark dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Use `struct` function to nest columns.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, unix_timestamp, struct

>>> df.select(struct(struct(col("id"), col("name"), unix_timestamp(col("created_at"))).alias("after")).alias("payload")).printSchema()
root
 |-- payload: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- after: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- col3: long (nullable = true)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, is there a way to do this dynamically without going through each column?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the idea that @Srinivas had (create the nested structure using struct) but doing it dynamically:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,struct,lit
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, LongType, StringType

# Initialize Spark Session
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

def nest_dataframe(df: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
    # Step 1: Identify column names and data types
    schema = df.schema
    col_names = [f.name for f in schema.fields]
    col_types = {f.name: f.dataType for f in schema.fields}

    # Step 2: Convert to desired data types
    for col_name in col_names:
        if col_types[col_name].typeName() == "timestamp":
            df = df.withColumn(col_name, col(col_name).cast("long"))

    # Step 3: Create the nested structure using struct
    nested_cols = [col(name) for name in col_names]
    after_struct = struct(nested_cols).alias("after")
    payload_struct = struct(after_struct).alias("payload")

    # Step 4: Apply nested structure
    new_df = df.select(payload_struct)
    
    return new_df
```

We can test this function with the following code:

```
# Sample DataFrame
data = [("1", "Alice", "2021-09-30 12:34:56"), ("2", "Bob", "2021-10-01 01:45:30")]
columns = ["id", "name", "created_at"]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
df = df.withColumn("created_at", col("created_at").cast("timestamp"))
df = df.withColumn("yet_another_column", lit(3))

# Use the function to get the nested DataFrame
nested_df = nest_dataframe(df)
nested_df.printSchema()
```

The output should be

```
root
 |-- payload: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- after: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- created_at: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- another_column: integer (nullable = false)
```

Try it with your actual dataframe and let us know if it worked as expected.